# scala mutable val List

Tags: list, scala, immutability, mutability

Few days ago I found Paul Philip’s gist https://gist.github.com/paulp/9085746 which shows quite strange behavior.
I did not find any explanation how is that possible

simplified code snippet:

```
val buf = new ListBuffer[Int]()
buf ++= Seq(1,2,3)
val lst: List[Int] = buf.toIterable.toList
println(lst) //List(1,2,3)
buf ++= Seq(4,5,6)
println(lst) //List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

It works as expected without `toIterable`

```
val buf = new ListBuffer[Int]()
buf ++= Seq(1,2,3)
val lst: List[Int] = buf.toList
println(lst) //List(1,2,3)
buf ++= Seq(4,5,6)
println(lst) //List(1,2,3)
```

What is going on there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'll look at the [`List` source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L434), you'll see that cons `::` class have its tail defined as `private[scala] var tl` not `val`, so it's internally mutable.

This mutation is occuring [during `ListBuffer` append](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L174) unless `exported` flag is set.

This flag is set in [the `toList` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L310), preventing further modification of the same `List`

But `toIterable` is inherited from `SeqForwarder` -> `IterableForwarder`, which has no knowledge about such thing, but is returning same `start` object [as it used as `underlying`  value](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L69)

Comment: @Dima I believe it is a bug

Comment: It seems like it isn't really to just `append`: for example, `buf -= 3` also mutates the `lst`